# Eiffel: Invalid constraint for formal generic paramete

Tags: generic-programming, eiffel

Following with strange patterns for some, can't I do that? The compiler says `Invalid constraint for formal generic parameter`

```
class PARENT[G -> CHILD[like Current]]

feature -- Access

    children: LIST[G]

end

class CHILD[H -> PARENT[like Current]]

feature -- Access

    father: H
end
```

to be able to do something like

```
class WIDOW_PARENT

inherit
    PARENT[BLACK_CHILD]

end

class BLACK_CHILD

inherit 
    CHILD[WIDOW_PARENT]

end
```

If I don't do it with genericity, I'd have to redefine the children collection from

- `children: LIST[CHILD]` to `children: LIST[BLACK_CHILD]` into the WIDOW_PARENT class
- `father: PARENT` to `father: WIDOW_PARENT` into the BLACK_CHILD class

instead of only specify it in the inherit clause... Hope it makes sense

### Update

As I solved it with Alexanders answer, I'm stuck further doing a conformity check. I'm trying to set an HTTP router depending on entities and if its a child entity it should be able to do a http://host:port/entity/child_entity/id to get all child entities from entity. For that I'd like to add to the generic router a check. On something like `ANY_PARENT_DB_ENTITY` such as

```
if ({G}).conforms_to ({CHILD_DB_ENTITY[ANY_PARENT_DB_ENTITY]}) then
    friend.act_like_a_father 
else
    friend.act_like_a_mate
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contemporary Eiffel, anchored types cannot be used in formal generic constraints, thus the error. It's still possible to have mutual constraints by repeating class types explicitly:

```
class PARENT [G -> CHILD [PARENT [G]]]
class CHILD  [H -> PARENT [CHILD [H]]]
```

With this change, the example compiles.

Comment: Many thx, unfortunately after, I'm stuck when want to express it in a conforms_to structure `if ({G}).conforms_to ({CHILD_DB_ENTITY[PARENT_DB_ENTITY[CANNOT_PUT_ANY_SO_GOES_TO_INFINITE]]}) then`, restriction or just wrong design pattern...

Comment: @Pipo Isn't it `({G}).conforms_to ({CHILD_DB_ENTITY [PARENT_DB_ENTITY [G]]})`?

Comment: Unfortunately G is a DB_ENTITY [G->DB_ENTITY] otherwise I wont need to check for conformity ;-) but thx!

Comment: Edited my question to add this issue

Comment: @Pipo Would adding non-generic parent classes `ABSTRACT_PARENT` and `ABSTRACT_CHILD`, inheritance links from `PARENT` to `ABSTRACT_PARENT`, and changing the constraints to `G -> ABSTRACT_CHILD` do?

Comment: yes, but then I'd have to change my collection and entity to specified types. This implies that I'd have to redefine them into children to avoid casting them... loosing polymorphism, see https://github.com/phgachoud/sit_eiffel in case...

Answer (score 0):

Being still the best solution for me, the only solution to my whole pattern is to redefine in my router class the `set_handler` method with

### CHILD_DB_ENTITY

```
deferred class
    CHILD_DB_ENTITY[H -> PARENT_DB_ENTITY[CHILD_DB_ENTITY[H]]]

inherit
    DB_ENTITY

feature 

    parent: H
```

### ENTITY_HANDLER

```
ENTITY_HANDLER[G -> DB_ENTITY, H -> DB_SERVICE[G] create make end]

feature

        item_prototype: detachable G

        set_handler
            do
                setting_url_("http://host:port/" + {like item_prototype}.out)
                ...
            end
end -- Class
```

### CHILD_ENTITY_HANDLER

```
CHILD_ENTITY_HANDLER[G -> CHILD_DB_ENTITY[PARENT_DB_ENTITY[G]], H -> DB_SERVICE[G]]

inherit
    ENTITY_HANDLDER
        redefine
            set_handler
        end

feature

        set_handler
            do
                Precursor
                setting_url_("http://host:port/" + ({like item_prototype}).out + "/" + ({like item_prototype.parent}).out + "/{id}")
            end

end -- Class
```

### PARENT_ENTITY_HANDLER

```
PARENT_ENTITY_HANDLER[G -> PARENT_DB_ENTITY[CHILD_DB_ENTITY[G]], H -> DB_SERVICE[G]]

inherit
    ENTITY_HANDLDER
        redefine
            set_handler
        end

feature

        set_handler
            do
                Precursor
                setting_url_("http://host:port/" + ({like item_prototype}).out + "/" + ({like item_prototype.children.item}).out + "/{id}")
                -- children being a LINKED_LIST[PARENT_DB_ENTITY]
            end

end -- Class
```

I hoped there was a way to get it with polymorphism in same class, but it also makes sense to have to redefine it that way...